# Extracting value from HTML Responce using Regular expression in JMETER?

Tags: html, regex, jmeter

I am getting response from Jmeter like this:

> <input type="hidden" id="queueItemId" name="queueItemId" value="3256"/>

I wanted to get value 3256 from this and store it in a variable. Then i can use this variable further use like `${variable}`. 
For this i am using `RegularExpressionExtractor` in scope of the Sampler.

Please give me the regular expression to extract this value.

Comment: Value 3256? Add more info please.

Comment: if that's the only query string that's ever appended why not split it on `=` and take the second group

Comment: in which language?? `Javascript` or  any server side language like `php`,`perl`, `python` etc..

Comment: do you want this :  http://rubular.com/r/MVcXXRRyzk

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
encounterId=([0-9]+)
```

and use group 1 as the result.

Comment: This doesn't work if the value contain leter and doesn't take account that you might have number in the id or name.

Comment: This question has been merged and my answer does not fit to the above question... I flagged it.

Answer (score 1):

Better than using regular expression to extract that value I would suggest using XPath Extraction like this:

```
//form[@name='MyForm']//input[@name='queueItemId']/@value
```

Where `MyForm` is your form name, replace with whatever you have.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the best awnser is from **Ibu** in the comment:

value=\"(\d+)\"
and: value="([^"]+?)"  will workfine too

So in jemter it will look like this:

> reference name: value
>
> Regex: (\s value=\"(\d+)\")
>
> Regex: (\s value="([^"]+?)")
>
> template : $2$
>
> match no.:1

If you want only the value that have the reference name *queueItemId* you might want to modify the reg ex to this.

So from jmeter reg ex extractor you got :

> reference name: queueItemId
>
> Regex: (name="queueItemId" \s value="([^"]+?)")
>
> Regex: (name="queueItemId" \s value=\"(\d+)\")
>
> template : $2$
>
> match no.:1

You should check the regex with jakarta oro because it's the reg ex engine that jmeter use.

Check out jakarta ORO here : http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/demo.html

ORO is a reg ex tool that behave almost exactly like jmeter.

Most of the time the the standart reg ex tool will work but it has happened to me sometime that the reg ex was fine in my tool but was not working in jmeter.

I later found out the ORO tool and was able to make it work in oro (and jmeter)

Another note: I think jmeter ignore space in your reg ex you have to add /s when you want to compare a space.

Answer (score 1):

The most maintainable way in recent version of JMeter is to use [CSS/JQuery Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor):

[image: Using CSS/JQuery]

The most performing one is to use new [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor):

[image: Boundary Extractor]

If you really want to use [Regular_Expression_Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) :

[image: Regex]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the XPath query:-

`//input[@type="hidden"][@id="queueItemId"][@name="queueItemId"]@value`

Answer (score 0):

or try this code
    regexId = '\d+';

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression will match the parameter and its value:

```
\bencounterId=(\d*)
```

The parentheses enable extraction of the value. Note the word boundary `\b` which makes sure a parameter ending with `encounterId` such as `fooencounterId` is not matched.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "<a href='/openmrs/module/moca/encounterViewer.form?encounterId=3537'></a>"
var regex = /<a.*?href='(.*?)'/;
var src = regex.exec(str)[1];
var numb = src.split("=")[1];
alert (numb);
```