# Extracting value from HTML Responce using Regular expression in JMETER?

Tags: html, regex, jmeter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extracting value from HTML Responce using Regular expression in JMETER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183643/extracting-value-from-html-responce-using-regular-expression-in-jmeter)

`<input type="hidden" id="queueItemId" name="queueItemId" value="3256"/>`

i want to get value 3256 using regular expression or xpath extractor in Jmeter. 
please give me the regularexpression?