# Regular expressions

Tags: html, regex, jmeter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extracting value from HTML Responce using Regular expression in JMETER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183643/extracting-value-from-html-responce-using-regular-expression-in-jmeter)

```
<a href="/openmrs/module/moca/encounterViewer.form?encounterId=3537">TestUpload<
```

I am getting the response like above. i want to get the value 3537 from this using regular expression or xPathextractor.

Please give me suggestions.